# Any font similar to skia? (note: not lithos)

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I'm looking for a font similar to Skia - but not Lithos, because the Lithos family is only in UPPERCASE and I want lowercase, bold Skia.

Answer (score 0):

[Nami font](http://www.identifont.com/find?similar=Nami&q=Go) from identifont.com.

[image]